# Javascript function is dropping attributes in my link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox, shadowbox

I'm having issues pulling the attributes even though they should be there. The attributes are needed for lightbox/shadowbox. Here's what I have so far.

The javascript code is set up to change the video url(depends on the language.)
I tried using the commented out code but wont work either.

JAVASCRIPT

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#video").on("change", function() {
     $('#video_link').html($(this).val()); // Pulls link from selection
     $("#video_link2").attr("href", ($(this).val())); // Pulls link from selection and inserts into href target

     // $("#video_link2").attr("rel", "lightbox[video]");
     // $("#video_link2").attr("data-ob_iframe", "true");
     // $("#video_link2").attr("data-ob", "lightbox[video]");

   }).change();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p style="text-align: center;">
  <a id="video_link2" href="" rel="lightbox[video]" data-ob_iframe="true" data-ob="lightbox[video]">
    <img width="100%" src="images/video-thumbnail.jpg" alt="Video Thumnail" />
  </a>
</p>

<select class="text_select" id="video" name="video">
  <option value="http://video.dow.com/viewerportal/external/embed.vp?programId=esc_program%3A44610&contentAssocId=association%3A77258&amp;autoplay=1">English - PacXpert&trade; Packaging Technology</option>
  <option value="http://video.dow.com/viewerportal/external/embed.vp?programId=esc_program%3A44905&contentAssocId=association%3A77800&amp;autoplay=1">Portuguese - Tecnologia PacXpert&trade; para Embalagens</option>
  <option value="http://video.dow.com/viewerportal/external/embed.vp?programId=esc_program%3A45501&contentAssocId=association%3A77826&amp;autoplay=1">Spanish - Tecnología PacXpert&trade; para empaques</option>
</select>
```

DEBUG CODE:

```
<p><span id="video_link"></span></p>
<p>This video is also available in the following languages: <a href="" id="video_link2">Link</a></p>
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what the issue is :/ Is it possible that you need to refresh or re-initialize lightbox/shadowbox once the attributes are changed. They are probably cached when initialized before the change.

Comment: "I'm having issues pulling the attributes..." what do you mean? Where are you trying to get the attributes? Please clarify your question!

Comment: Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ac8y41tk/) and it works. If you wonder why `<a href="" id="video_link2">Link</a>` doesn't have link - it's because there already is element with ID `video_link2` on page (`<a id="video_link2" href="" rel="lightbox[video]" ...`).

Comment: @Evilzebra <a id="video_link2" href="" rel="lightbox[video]" data-ob_iframe="true" data-ob="lightbox[video]"><img width="100%" src="images/video-thumbnail.jpg" alt="Video Thumnail"/></a> its not pulling, the "rel" "ob_iframe" ect...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
$("#video_link2").prop("href", $(this).val());
```

i hope this was helped you

Comment: Nope, it will be just the same.